Special header on the last page using Apache POI 5.3.0
When creating a document I need to insert a special footer on the last page. My problem is that when creating a document, a paragraph can be between two pages. So, I need to find the last word in the paragraph, which is on the second to last page, and split one paragraph into two and insert a section break between them. I found how to make a section break:
public static void createSectionBreak(XWPFDocument document){
        CTBody body = document.getDocument().getBody();
        CTSectPr sectPr = body.getSectPr();
        if (sectPr != null) {
            XWPFParagraph lastParagraph = document.createParagraph();
            lastParagraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().setSectPr(sectPr);
            body.unsetSectPr();
        }
        document.createParagraph().setPageBreak(true);
    }

To find the word where I need to make a paragraph break, I want to delete the content piece by piece and use the number of pages to determine where I need to insert a break. To get information about the number of pages in a document I found the following code:
public static int getPagesInDoc(XWPFDocument document) {
        return document.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
}

But this option works poorly. It gives the same number regardless of the actual state of the document. The original template has two pages. After working with the document, there are four, but this method still returns two. Even if I write the file and open it again, the result is the same. Perhaps there is a different way to solve my problem or a method for obtaining the current number of pages (preferably without closing the file)?
I use the currently up-to-date library Apache POI 5.3.0.
